# Автоматизация Selenium python на discord.com

Tags: python, selenium

делаю проект для автоматизации Discord в браузере Dolphin Anty.
Я использую Selenium 3.14.0.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, после нажатия на кнопку "Принять приглашение", всплывает уведомление, что сайт хочет открыть десктопное приложение, которое мешает остальным действиям.
[image: данное уведомление]

Пытался отлавливать его через `driver.switch_to_alert()`
Но всегда выдает ошибку *No such alert*, не зависимо от того сколько сколько я жду.

**В процессе этого кода вылезает данное уведомление.**

```
driver.get('https://discord.gg/RHFvCxdx')
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').click()
time.sleep(3)
```

**Настройки дравйерв**

````
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"127.0.0.1:{port}")
    chrome_driver = "C:\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо открыть приложение? Или ограничить вывод таких всплывающих окон?

Если нужно только ограничить, то это возможно сделать через установку дополнительных экспериментальных опций. Конкретно за это отвечает  **--disable-default-apps**

```
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option(
    'excludeSwitches',
    ['disable-default-apps'])
```